# What is the best way to represent a complicated truth table in Java or other OO/non-functional languages?

Tags: java, oop, functional-programming

I am implementing a lot of complicated business logic that is represented in a truth table/business rules matrix. In the past, implementing these rules has often resulted in a lot of `if...else` statements. I can't help but think that a functional language lends itself to expressing these rules more elegantly.

How can I make implementation in Java less painful?

What are some helpful patterns when doing this?

Comment: write a lot of tests.  if users can modify rules, make it clear what effects their changes have, e.g., your latest edit changed % of FOO classifications from 99 to 5 and increased BAR from .5% to 66%.  make it impossible to specify contradictions.

Comment: Can you give an example of your current implementation?  I realize it uses if/else statements; I'm looking for a representation of how complex the rules are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [business rules engine](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Business_rules_engine) instead of writing the rules directly in Java. There exists a [standard Java API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/JavaRule.html) for these things.

Alternatively, write your rules in a language that supports pattern matching to reduce the number of conditionals. [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/120) comes to mind.

Comment: I have thought about doing this, but it seems that many tools like [Jess](http://www.jessrules.com/) require your application to really be structured with its use in mind. Client requirements make this impossible. Plus, this is a fairly minor subset of the application. I'm hoping for something lighter in weight.

Comment: @pkananen: updated my answer with a recommendation to use Scala and a link to the appropriate feature.

Comment: I would love to use Scala. It's a no-go at this point in the project, and for the client in general. I wish I could fight that battle, but now I can't.

Comment: @pkananen: then the only thing I can come up with now is to implement a poor man's business rules engine, i.e. an algorithm such as Rete or just a bunch of classes that wrap if-then rules. In any case, I think doing this is in an OO/datacentric way may win you more than FP.